# Does running a PowerShell script using an embedded System.Managment.Automation DLL prevent it from being scanned by AMSI?

Tags: antivirus, powershell

A new feature called [Antimalware Scan Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dn889587(v=vs.85).aspx), that allow AVs to 'see' Powershell commands executed, was introduced in Powershell v5.

According to [adsecurity](https://adsecurity.org/?p=2277), this feature seems to rely on the system-wide `System.Management.Automation.dll` assembly:

> When code is delivered to the PowerShell “engine” (System.Management.Automation.dll), it is sent to the AMSI for anti-malware checks.

Does that mean AMSI would not work if a PowerShell script is executed from an embedded `System.Management.Automation.dll` assembly into an executable?

Comment: Yes, AMSI is detected by specific PS engine dll version (starting with PS5.0) engine, so if you deploy V4.0, then AMSI won't be used.